# Code design for main program + configuration module

Tags: python, c++, c, sockets, named-pipes

I have a main program **X** which is getting feed from my webcam.
I want to configure **X** in real-time while it's executing.
I understand that one of the common ways of doing that is using IPC like named-pipes/Unix sockets/Internet sockets, etc. But I want to avoid each caller to have to separately open a socket/named-pipe, and communicate each time.
In short, I want a helper program by the name **Y**, which I can use in the following manner:

```
Y set-fps=15
Y show-frame=true
Y get-fps  (should return 15)
```

I would want to play this helper program **Y** in /usr/bin/* (or rather place it in one of $PATH directoreis) so that it's  executable from the command-line.

What are my options for obtaining this functionality. My constraints are as under:
(i) Program **X** could be either C++/Python.
(ii) Multiple clients could call **Y** simultaneously.

I guess such systems are common on linux where you have programs like `nmcli` interacting with services like the `network-manager` ?

Comment: You still need some kind of IPC channel between the programs Y and X. And if you're worried about multiple external systems or programs using Y simultaneously, then you could use some kind of semaphore/mutex system (most operating systems have named (system-wide) semaphores).

Comment: That sounds unpleasant. I'd recommend rethinking the design.

Comment: I guess to handle multiple clients, named-pipes might be too much to use (since I will need one pair for every client who tries to connect). I want to be able to handle multiple clients simultaneously with/without blocking (depending upon the request).

Comment: @EOF: Can you please elaborate? Such a design makes it easy for any client to easily communicate. How else could I achieve that..

Comment: And can UNIX sockets handle multiple clients simultaneously and exclusively?

Comment: UNIX sockets might be what you're looking for. I don't think you can avoid each caller having to open a new connection. It might be easiest for the main program to have a separate thread to handle connections.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to put that post in answer, i still can't comment.

one of the way i could see to do such is the following :

as your program takes frames from the webcam, there is certainly a loop or a redundant automat.

In this way, you could allocate some registers in the kernel memory in one block, each of registers being one of the parameter.

then, at each loop, your X program could read the different parameters from that kernel space. On the other side, each client who wants to modify the parameters will access this kernel space too, and modify the required values.

Then, you have to protect the kernel space with a semaphore, for any write or read operation.(a mutex is ok there, however you may want some writer/reader implementation)

Of course, this is not optimal in performance compared to a protection for each one of the parameters, but with that you have to handle only one semaphore, and a simple mutex would do the job. It's certainly also less beautiful than a communication with pipes or sockets, but with them, you would still have to protect the read and write of your parameters...

Comment: I can't go with this approach, otherwise I will have to always keep checking what values have changed. And actually my program X also may have to return an output to program Y. So this won't work out. Thanks for your comment.